# How to upload photo in yii?

Tags: php, image, yii

i am not able to upload photo in my database and folder... this same code is working if i use CModel class for building form... but if i am using plain html it's giving me error `Profilepic cannot be blank`... my code is given below

**my form**

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/index.php?r=user/create'?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username"/><span><?php if(isset($error['username'])) echo $error['username'][0]; ?></span>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password"/><span><?php if(isset($error['password'])) echo $error['password'][0]; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email"/><span><?php if(isset($error['email'])) echo $error['email'][0]; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Profile pic</label><input type="file" name="profilepic"/><span><?php if(isset($error['profilepic'])) echo $error['profilepic'][0]; ?></span>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="No" name="flag"/>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
```

**my controller method**

```
   public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
                    $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profilepic');
                    $fileName = "{$uploadedFile}";  
                    $model->profilepic = $fileName;
        $model->attributes=$_POST;

                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        $a=$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$fileName);
                        $this->redirect(array('create'));
                    }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**my rules method array**

```
     return array(
        array('username, password,email,profilepic', 'required'),
        array('email','email'),
                    array('profilepic','file','types'=>'jpg,jpeg,png'),
                    array('email','unique'),
        array('username,password,email,flag,profilepic', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
```

can somebody help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change controller code like follow...

```
public function actionCreate()
{
   $model=new User;
   if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) //change it
   {
                $model->profilepic=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('profilepic');
               // $fileName = "{$uploadedFile}"; //this is not required  
               // $model->profilepic = $fileName; //this is also not required
                $model->attributes=$_POST;

                if($model->save())
                {
                    $model->profilepic->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$model->profilepic);
                    $this->redirect(array('create'));
                }
   }

   $this->render('create',array(
       'model'=>$model,
   )); 
}
```

above all changes you need required... and one most important thing i changed is **getInstanceByName('profilepic')**

Hope it may solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at it line by line (some specific lines):

1) $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profilepic');
You're using "getInstance" method from CUploadedFile Yii class. Keep in mind that there's a nice documentation for Yii stuff, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile is for CUploadedFile class.

2) $fileName = "{$uploadedFile}";
Here's your trying to take the temp filename retrieved by "getInstance" from above. And here's the first catch: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstance-detail
public static CUploadedFile getInstance(CModel $model, string $attribute) - this is what "getInstance" is expecting. As you see, the first parameter is $model, that is the instance of model inherited from CModel and for unknown reasons you're trying to avoid CModel. 
So, when you're calling "getInstance", this method simply doesn't know what you're calling exactly (especially when "User" class is not shown at your question). This is why the 3rd line will spit "Profilepic can't be blank", nothing is returned from "getInstance" method and nothing for "Profilepic" to operate with.

3) $model->profilepic = $fileName;
I guess now it's clear for you why there's an error.

So, you can either load a model (getting back to CModel) or at least should take a deeper look on what you have for "User" class (taken from $model=new User;) and pay more attention to Yii documentation.

Hopefully this will give you at least some direction and no offence meant, i'm just one of Yii documentation fans.